# Need to use a variable in a getElementsByTagName function

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

The code below runs fine with a hard-coded tag name.  I need to be able to call "loadDoc" with a variable that will return the tag I specify.  I am rather new to JQuery and I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Many thanks.

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      myFunction(xhttp);
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "pyg280c.xml", true);
  xhttp.send(); 
  }

function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var htext = "";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PYP280CR");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
      htext += "<p>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("PCST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</p>";
  }
  document.getElementById("helptext").innerHTML = htext;
}
```

Comment: `function loadDoc(myTagName)` ??

Comment: Thanks but the part that I cannot seem to get right is the 
    htext += "<p>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("PCST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</p>";
part.  When I put the variable in place of PCST it does not work.  I'm not sure I have the syntax correct.

Comment: So pass in a variable to the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say it works fine when you hardcode the tag name then as @Hackerman said pass the tagname into the loadDoc function. Pass it on to the myFunction function and simply use the tag name variable in the getElementByTagName(tag) function (no quotes around variables). It should work.

```
function loadDoc(myTagName) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      myFunction(xhttp, myTagName);
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "pyg280c.xml", true);
  xhttp.send(); 
  }

function myFunction(xml, tag) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var htext = "";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PYP280CR");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
      htext += "<p>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName(tag)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</p>";
  }
  document.getElementById("helptext").innerHTML = htext;
}
```

FYI - You mentioned jQuery. There is no jQuery in your code. jQuery probably would have made this easier.

Jquery version including some default ajax error handling:

```
function loadDoc(tag){
    $.ajax({
        url: "pyg280c.xml",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
                    var xmlDOC = $.parseXML(xml.responseXML);
                    var x = $(xmlDOC).find("PYP280CR");
                    var htexts = $.map(x, function(el, idx){
                        return $(el).find(tag).children()[0].val();
                    }
                    htext = htexts.join(" ");
                    $('#helptext').html(htext);
                 },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    console.log('status = ' + xhr.status);
                    console.log('error = ' + thrownError);
               } 

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I think that is where I got confused.  The process I am working on uses a lot of JQuery and I incorrectly assumed there was some special way of referring to a variable.  I'm still very green with these languages and very much appreciate you taking the time to explain this.

Best regards. :-)